# Add new language for setup project .net setup

Tags: .net, setup-project

i am able to locate this property which actually works fine but it has only contains few languages. How do i **add norwegian**?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you need to make sure all the strings in your application are resources (instead of hard-coded string literals), and you create new resources for each language:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688096

This is an old article (circa 2003) ... but you can't get any better than John Robbins and, as far as I can tell, all the information he provides is still accurate:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163991.aspx

This is all true for .Net applications in general.

As far as installer projects, it's basically the same thing.  Here are some extra details:

http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-internationalization/589/How-to-I18N-a-Setup-project

'Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info , i was able to locate the property for localization but the question has changed now for me , so please have a look into that.. thanks

Comment: Your question *did* change - pretty substantially ;-)  They're called "language packs".  Look here (among other places): http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/language-packs

Comment: i do have norwegian installed in my system but it still doesnot show up in the localization drop down

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480243.aspx

You need to download "Dotnetfx.exe" file from here(http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19) and try to execute like \Runtime\dotnetfx.exe

Hope it will help you.